# ¿Cómo se instala correctamente boostrap en android? (Error: Gradle project sync failed.)

Tags: android, android-studio, bootstrap

Tengo un proyecto de android al cual le quiero implementar boostrap y al parecer ya lo hice. Utilicé la importación de módulos que tiene android studio y después de que realice eso mi código dejo de funcionar y no me deja correrlo, me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your proyect and try again

y también me sale este error:

> Error:(5, 0) Could not get unknown property 'TARGET_SDK_INT' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Este segundo error ya lo modifiqué en la línea que me dice:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_INT)
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode = Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
        versionName = VERSION_NAME
    }
}
```

Código del buildgradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        compile group: 'com.github.yamingd.android', name: 'bootstrap', version: '2.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build gradle de boostrap

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'push.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_INT)
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode = Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
        versionName = VERSION_NAME
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.github.yamingd.android', name: 'bootstrap', version: '2.0.0'
}
```

Si sincronizo los build gradles con mi proyecto me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: David, agrega completo tu build.gradle por favor.

Comment: @jorgesys ya agregue el código del build

Comment: Espera pero la dependencia debe de estar en el mismo archivo build.gradle donde defines targetSdkVersion !

Comment: @Jorgesys ah ya es que tengo el build.gradle de boostrap y el de mi app

Comment: @Jorgesys ya agregue el otro build

Comment: Sincroniza tus archivos build.gradle con el proyecto.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo realice y modifique la publicación de arriba con el error que me sale.

Answer (score 0):

Las constantes `MIN_SDK_INT`, `VERSION_CODE`, `VERSION_NAME` no pueden ser leidas, debes asegurar agregar la dependencia para usar Android Bootstrap en el archivo `build.gradle` de tu proyecto!

```
compile group: 'com.github.yamingd.android', name: 'bootstrap', version: '2.0.0'
```

Revisa [Android Bootstrap dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.yamingd.android/bootstrap/2.0.0) para agregar la versión correcta.